# mysql query for Ordered proximity

Tags: php, mysql, search

everyone

i am stuck with some problem in mysql. what i am trying to do is searching the database table and i have a condition here.

for example:-

**"corporate tax law"/10**

when i input the above search it should return the rows.. with 'corporate', 'tax' and 'law' within 10 words in field column1.
what should be the query for the above(juss mysql query will be great). can anybody help on this :). will be glad to see any of the comments

thank you for reading my question,

anstrangelover

Comment: That's very logical, have you tried anything ?

Comment: can u provide some sample example?

Comment: no i havent started with with any code. juss wandering about the sql so that i can integrate it with my code.

Comment: @CRDave juss like when i have a table with column1 data as "this is testing message for mysql query Ordered proximity." now i have to get row in such a way that dat it search 'message, mysql, proximity'but these should lies within 10 words..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the fulltext search capabilities in MySql. There is a `proximity` feature described part way down the article here:

http://www.drdobbs.com/database/full-text-search-with-innodb/231902587?pgno=2